# d-disonnection in X using induced metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am really struggling with this question about finding a d-disconnection of X.

$X=\mathbb R^2 -\{(x,y):y=1\}$

The metric, *d*, is

$\textit{d}(\textbf{x,y})=max\{|x_1 -y_1|,|x_2 -y_2|\}$

The suggestion is sets U and V where $U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y<1\}$ and $V=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y>1\}$.

I can visualise $\mathbb R^2$ being cut in two by the sets U and V but cant picture a way to describe them as being simultaneeously d-closed and d-open. Any help much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What properties of open and closed sets are you familiar with?

Comment: It is enough to show that both are open. That makes them automatically closed because they are complements of each other. And you show they are open by the classical property: every point in $U$ belongs to $U$ together with some small open ball around it.

Comment: Would it work by having a sequence in U  - (0,1-1/n) that d-converges on the point (0,1) that is not in U, thus making U open. The complement of U in X is V which then would be closed. And then flip this reasoning around with the sequence (0, 1+1/n) making V open and U its closed complement in X?

Comment: @JonPercival that property does not make a subset open. It makes it "not closed" if the limit exists. But in this case its even worse: the limit $(0,1)$ does not belong to $X$. That reasoning is incorrect.